# Chrome developer tools local modifications broken

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Am i missing something or did i manage to break it somehow?

Iv set a breakpoint and would like to do some debugging there without having to edit the js code each time and reloading the whole page.
The "local modifications" options only opens new drawer with empty history tab and nothing else.

While console does show most variables - it does not help if a structure similar to this is used:

```
rate += Number(oldRates[key]) / 100;
```

Without logging or assigning it to a variable, i do not know what oldRates[key] actually returns (besides looking at what value this key has).

This is where a local modification to separately log this part out or assign to a variable would be useful.

Comment: The question is still relevant. The dev tools do not work.

Answer (score 1):

Local Modifications appear in the History tab and show when you make a changes to the Sources and Save them. It allows you to revert those changes without reloading the application. See [Demo](http://blittle.github.io/chrome-dev-tools/sources/local-modifications.html).

You can use a [Watch Expression](http://albertlee.azurewebsites.net/using-watch-tools-in-chrome-dev-tools-to-improve-your-debugging/) to view the current state of an object during execution.

[image: watch]

In the example above, I paused after I created the object. I added a watch on the `obj` variable and now I can see all keys and values in the watch Panel. I don't have to constantly log it to the console.

Comment: That's the problem - it just opens the history but i still cant edit the script itself. I's as if its still read only or something.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot or example? I'm not too sure what you mean.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Nt4In
this is what i see after i rclick and choose "local modifications"

Comment: It looks like you are looking at an evaluated script, hence the `VM` prefix. You can't make modifications to these generated scripts.